# User Skips Permission in Facebook Auth Dialogue Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication

I have an app in a page tab that uses the facebook javascript sdk.  When a new user comes to the app, I get the expected "Log in with facebook" pop-up.  I also have some extended permissions that I've put in the scope parameter of FB.Login.  After the users logs in with facebook I see the expected extended permissions pop-up.  The only problem is if the user skips the extended permissions, the dialogue returns back an access_token, but it's not valid for the extended permissions.  Code example below.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    FB.init({
        appId: facebookAppId, 
        status: true, // check login status
    });

    function updateFBInfo(response) {
        console.log('updateResp:');
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user is already logged in and connected
            FB.api('/me', function (info) {
                displayUserInfo(info, response);
            });
        }
        else {
            FB.login(function (loginResponse) {
                if (loginResponse.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function (info) {
                        displayUserInfo(info, loginResponse);
                    });
                }
            }, { scope: 'email,manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream' });
        }
    }

    FB.getLoginStatus(updateFBInfo);
};
```

I guess my question is either, what am I missing (this has got to be something easy), or is there a way to check and see if the returned acces_token is actually valid?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to check explicitly for the permission before proceeding.  If they haven't provided the necessarily permissions, you need to display `FB.login()` with the necessary scope again.

Here is the code for checking permissions:

```
FB.api('/me/permissions', function (response) {
            var perms = response.data[0];
            // Check for publish_stream permission in this case....
            if (perms.publish_stream) {                
                // User has permission
            } else {                
                // User DOESN'T have permission. Perhaps ask for them again with FB.login?
            }                                            
    } );
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the quick response.  I knew it was something simple.

Comment: A way to do this check from a variable like this?:

var scope = 'user_friends,user_birthday,user_education_history' ?

Comment: You'll have to loop through each value. E.g. var permValue = 'user_friends';if(permValue in perms) {... }